# Convert byte[] to string in Java when reading Pid

Tags: java, parsing, parseint

I'm trying to get the Pid of my application under Ubuntu with the following code:

```
    byte[] bo = new byte[100];
    String[] cmd = { "bash", "-c", "echo $PPID" };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.getInputStream().read(bo);
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(bo));
```

But I'm getting this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10961\n`

Why does to converting to string adds a " ? I think the \n the parseInt can handle... Is a encoding problem?

Thanks,

Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` is a unix newline character. You can strip it before sending to `parseInt()`.

```
return Integer.parseInt(new String(bo).replace("\n", ""));
```

Comment: or more generally `new String(bo).trim()`

Comment: @FrancisUpton Thanks for the elegant trim()

Answer (score 2):

You get the NumberFormat Exception because `\n` isn't a numeric character.  You can either strip the trailing `\n`:

```
return Integer.parseInt(new String(bo).replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

or get `echo` not to add one in the first place:

```
String[] cmd = { "bash", "-c", "echo -n $PPID" };
```